# Regex Multiple Strings With "or" Operator

Tags: java, regex

I need to establish a java regex that will recognize the following 3 cases:

1. Any combination/amount of the following characters: "ACTGactg:"

or

2. Any single question marks "?"

or

3. Any string "NTC"

I will list what I have tried so far and the errors that have arisen.

```
public static final VALID_STRING = "[ACTGactg:]*";
// Matches the first case but not the second or third
// as expected.

public static final VALID_STRING = "\\?|[ACTGactg:]*";
// Matches all 3 conditions when my understanding leads me to
// believe that it should not except the third case of "NTC"

public static final VALID_STRING = "?|[ACTGactg:]*";
// Yields PatternSyntaxException dangling metacharacter ?
```

What I would expect to be accurate is the following:

```
public static final VALID_STRING = "NTC|\\?|[ACTGacgt:]*";
```

But I want to make sure that if I take away the "NTC" that any "NTC" string will appear as invalid.

Here is the method I am using to test these regexs.

```
private static boolean isValid(String thisString){
    boolean valid = false;
    Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(VALID_STRING);
    Matcher matchRegex = checkRegex.matcher(thisString);
    while (matchRegex.find()){
        if (matchRegex.group().length != 0){
            valid = true;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

So here are my closing questions:

1. Could the "\\?" regex possible be acting as a wild card character that is accepting the "NTC" string?
2. Are the or operators "|" appropriate here?
3. Do I need to make use of parenthesis when using these or operators?

Here are some example incoming strings:

- A:C
- T:G
- AA:CC
- T:C:A:G
- NTC
- ?

Thank you

Comment: Since you have a proposed solution, why not just test it and see if it works, and try it with and without parentheses?

Comment: Which object/method are you using to test the strings?

Comment: @DNA Great point. I have tried many different combinations and have lost track of all the individual results. I guess I am asking what the rules/conventions are.

Comment: @RealSkeptic give me a second and I will include the method I am using.

Comment: Can you provide some example of strings that should match and that shouldn't? Should the regex match the whole string? Like `NTC`, `Atgc`, `?`?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the provided regex would be ok:

```
public static final VALID_STRING = "NTC|\\?|[ACTGacgt:]+";
```

...

```
boolean valid = str.matches(VALID_STRING);
```

If your remove `NTC|` from the regex the string NTC becomes invalid.

You can test it and experiment yourself [here](https://regex101.com/r/oS0aR9/2).

Comment: Or use `matches` instead of `find`. `find` looks for any substring, `matches` doesn't.

Comment: You are right, `matches` doesn't need line start and end anchors, I modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: I think I would like to keep find because it is helpful for other regexs that I check in the program, so I will keep find while using the anchored approach.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the `Matcher.find()` method, you are looking for your pattern anywhere in the string.

This means the strings `A:C`, `T:G`, `AA:CC` etc. match in their entirety. But how about `NTC`?

It matches because `find()` looks for a match anywhere. the `TC` part of it matches, therefore you get `true`.

If you want to match only the strings in their entirety, either use the `match()` method, or use `^` and `$`.

Note that you don't have to check that the match is longer than 0, if you change your pattern to `[ACTGactg:]+` instead of `[ACTGactg:]*`.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation this certainly makes sense.